# How to get access to uiTableViewCell which are not selected in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode9

So basically I know that I can get all the selected cells using "**selectedIndexPathRows**". But I want to change behavior of cells which are not selected. Also I want to know which cells are not selected on didSelect or didDeselect .
Basically, what I want to achieve is to get all the cells which are not selected and set their alpha to 0.5 and set 1.0 of only selected cells, how can I do that?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving hint for achieve that

- Take one array, size of array = total row of table
- Set initial value 0 at all index of array
- in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method first check, array has 0 value then change value 0 to 1 at specific index of array.
- Now array has 0 value that means this rows are not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to configure tableViewCell on select or deselect event.
Only override 'setSelected' method in subclass of UITableViewCell.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if selected{
        //configure on select
        //alpha = 1.0
    }else{
        //configure on deselect
        //alpha = 0.5
    }
}
```